# convert from english to predicate formulas

Tags: predicate-logic

Propositions, Predicates and Quantifiers [16 Points]

Consider the predicates defined below, where the domain is the ISU community.

1. $L(x, y)$ means  "$x$ and $y$ went to lunch together today"
2. $S(x)$ means "$x$  is a student"
3. $F(x)$ means "$x$ is faculty"

Translate the following assertions into predicate formulas:

> b) $y$ and $z$ are the only two faculty members that had lunch with at least two different students today

Comment: 'Translate the following..." usually means that something follows. Presumably, this means you copied and pasted from somewhere, and the "following" is actually in your title?

Comment: following is the assertion           y and z are the only two faculty members that had lunch with at least two different students today.

Comment: @BarkhaMathur Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried it as ∃x ∃y z ∃a ∃b ∃c ∃d ∃e F(x) ^ F(y) ^ F(z) ^ S(a) ^ S(b) ^ S(c) ^ S(d) ^ S(e) ^ L(x,a)^ L(x,b) ^ L(y,c) ^ L(y,d) ^ (z≠x) ^ (z≠y) ^ L(z,e)